# Radius of convergence of power series $\sum_0^{\infty} n!x^{n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

Radius of convergence of power series $\sum_0^{\infty} n!x^{n^2}$.

I applied ratio test, it went inconclusive  and in root test i got $|x|^n n!^{1/n}$ but $n!^{1/n} $ diverges as n gets bigger.

So please help me to proceed

Comment: I realize there is already an accepted answer, but just a a note: the ratio test is not inconclusive. Here we have $$a_n = n! x^{n^2}$$ and so $$\lvert a_{n+1}/a_n \rvert = (n+1) \lvert x \rvert ^{2n+1} = (n+1) e^{(2n+1)\log(\lvert x \rvert)}.$$ Now if $\lvert x \rvert < 1$, so that $\log(\lvert x \vert) < 0$, then this is a decaying exponential and the limit is zero as $n \to \infty$. If $ \lvert x \rvert \ge 1$, then this limit is $+\infty$. Hence the ratio test tells us that we have convergence iff $\lvert x \rvert < 1$.

Comment: @User8128 thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Note that we have

$$  \limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left| n!x^{n^2}\right|}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}(n!)^{1/n}|x|^n$$

Now use Stirling' s Formula

$$n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\left( \frac ne \right)^n$$

Comment: does error in stirling approximation tends to 0 as n gets bigger??

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: No, but $$n!=\left(\sqrt{2\pi n}\left( \frac ne \right)^n\right)\,\left(1+O(1/n)\right)$$

Comment: idk who downvote  but i accept yours !

Comment: Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 4):

The power series is $\sum_0^\infty a_m x^m$ where
$$
a_m = \begin{cases}
n!, & m = n^2, n \in \mathbb N^*\\
0, & \ \text{otherwise}, 
\end{cases}
$$
so by Hadamard formula, 
$$
1/R =\varlimsup |a_m|^{1/m} = \varlimsup (n!)^{1/n^2} =\varlimsup (\sqrt{2\pi} n^{n+1/2} \mathrm e^{-n})^{1/n^2} = \lim (2\pi)^{1/2n^2} n^{1/n} n^{1/2n^2}\mathrm  e^{-1/n} = 1, 
$$
where we use the Stirling approximation. Hence the radius of convergence is $1$.

Comment: Nothing wrong with using Stirling's formula, but more simply, for $n\ge 1 $ we have $1\le(n!)^{1/n^2}\le (n^n)^{1/n^2}=n^{1/n} \to 1$ as $ n\to\infty$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thanks for this trick!

Comment: @xbh does error in stirling approximation tends to 0 as n gets bigger?? also is it valid to take$1/n^2$ th root of x... please explain

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem. its not mentioned in hereto take 1/n^2 root , im confused.

Comment: @CloudJR I think my answer has said everything you need. The given series is a power series that a lot of terms lost, and $(n!)^{1/n}$ is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula is wrong because the exponent of $x$ is $n^2,$ but you can use the Weak form of Stirling’s Formula
\begin{align} \dfrac{n^n}{e^{n-1}}<n!<\dfrac{n^{n+1}}{e^{n-1}} . \end{align}
This implies that
\begin{align}  \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} n!{x^{n^2}}\leq \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \dfrac{n^{n+1}}{e^{n-1}} {x^{n^2}}. \end{align}
So, fix $x\in \Bbb{R},$ then by D'Alembert's ratio test
\begin{align}  \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left|\dfrac{n^{n+2}{x^{(n+1)^2}}}{e^{n}}  \dfrac{e^{n-1}} {n^{n+1} x^{n^2}}\right|&=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left|\dfrac{n }{e}  {x^{(n+1)^2-n^2}}\right|\\&=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left|\dfrac{n }{e}  {x^{2n+1}}\right|\\&=\dfrac{\left|x \right|}{e}  \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}n\,  {\left|x\right|}^{2n}. \end{align}

**CASE I: $|x|<1$**

Since $|x|<1$, then ${\left|x\right|}^{2n}\to 0$, and so, there exists $N\in \Bbb{N}$ such that 
\begin{align}  {\left|x\right|}^{2n}<\dfrac{1}{n^2},\forall\;n\geq N .\end{align} 
Thus,
\begin{align}  \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left|\dfrac{n^{n+2}{x^{(n+1)^2}}}{e^{n}}  \dfrac{e^{n-1}} {n^{n+1} x^{n^2}}\right|&=\dfrac{\left|x \right|}{e}  \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}n\,  {\left|x\right|}^{2n}\leq \dfrac{\left|x \right|}{e}  \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}n\, \left(\dfrac{1}{n^2}\right)=0<1. \end{align}
Hence, the series converges when $|x|<1.$

**CASE II: $|x|\geq 1$**
\begin{align}  \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}n!{x^{n^2}}=\infty \end{align}
which implies that the series cannot not converge. Consequently, the radius of convergence is $1$.